# How do I update android studio's gradle?

Tags: flutter, gradle

This is what I'm receiving from Android Studio, but I don't know how to fix this in the latest version.

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. 
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']    
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4.
```

---

**Edit**: I changed the **gradle-wrapper.properties** to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

And now also went to File/Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Gradle, and changed the **Gradle User Home** to a **gradle-5.6.4** that I downloaded.
But now, I'm receiving this:

```
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: post your full log error.also run `flutter clean` ,invalidate cache if using android studio and then run your project

Comment: run your project with "flutter release --verbose" to see what is the problem